# Change textFrame content with given styled text

Tags: javascript, scripting, jsx, adobe-indesign

Let's say I have a given `TextFrame`, and I want to completely substitute its content with my own text - which is going to contain some text in bold and a newline - how should I go about it?

The final text should be something like:

```html
<b>WORD</b><br>
NEW WORD
```

**What I've tried so far:**

```
var frame = app.activeDocument.textFrames.item("scr-hello");

var myStringsAndStyles = [
    {
      contents: "WORD",
      characterStyle: bold
    },
    {
      contents: "NEW WORD",
      characterStyle: none
    }
  ];

  with (frame.insertionPoints ) {
    for ( var i = 0, arrlength = myStringsAndStyles.length; i < arrlength; i++ ) {
      lastItem().properties = {
        contents: myStringsAndStyles[i].contents,
        appliedCharacterStyle: myStringsAndStyles[i].characterStyle
      }
    }
  }
```

**The problem is:**

- We are not replacing the TextFrame's content; we are adding to it
- The newline is not there
- The result is a mess (it's not even the two strings I supposedly added, one after the other)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
var frame = app.activeDocument.textFrames.item('scr-hello');
frame.contents = 'WORD\nNEW WORD';              // fill the frame with the text
var line = frame.parentStory.texts[0].lines[0]; // get the first line from the frame
line.fontStyle = 'Bold';                        // assign Bold style
```

But you have to make sure that the font has Bold style. Some fonts have no additional styles.

Just in case, here is the extended example with character styles:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// get the styles
var style_none = doc.characterStyles[0]; // '[None]'
var style_bold = doc.characterStyles.item('Bold');

// create the 'Bold' style if there is no such style
if (!style_bold.isValid) {
    style_bold = doc.characterStyles.add();
    style_bold.name = 'Bold';
    style_bold.fontStyle = 'Bold';
}

// get the frame and change its contents
var frame = app.activeDocument.textFrames.item('scr-hello');
frame.contents = 'WORD\nNEW WORD';
var story = frame.parentStory;

// remove the old formatting
story.texts.everyItem().appliedCharacterStyle = style_none;
story.texts.everyItem().clearOverrides();

// apply the 'Bold' style to the first line
var line = story.texts[0].lines[0].appliedCharacterStyle = style_bold;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll give it a try and will let you know! :)